# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried just about every way I can think to search for this issue. Many similar, but I cannot find any that pertain to a period being an unrecognized expression.

I know this is bad form, but the relevant code is so convoluted, I'm going to only post a little, until someone asks for a specific amount more.

So, I have the following jQuery:
`$($('.zonePage:not(.zoneTowns)').get().reverse()).each(function(i){`

This selector/expression was working fine when last I ran the code. No changes were made in the interim, so it's totally baffling to me that I can be experiencing this.

If I `console.log($($('.zonePage:not(.zoneTowns)').get().reverse()));` I get the expected output: a listing of the 8 matched elements. However, even when attempting to assign this collection to a variable first
`var zp=$('.zonePage:not(.zoneTowns)').get().reverse();`
`$(zp).each(function(i){`

I am still told that `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .`

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

After remote troubleshooting, it was realized that the OP is a dummy and did not analyze the correct level of the error trace. CertainPerformance sussed it out in about a minute.
`/* if(needTot[m][s]<=warnings[s]) */$('#scarce'+zo).find('.'+m).find('.'+s).text(needTot[m][s]);`

Comment: @CertainPerformance the jQuery is hardcoded into a php file which is 488 lines and resultantly generates a 79514 line mess of HTML and redundant javascript. Can you advise on how to encapsulate this for a live snippet?

Comment: @CertainPerformance not at all sure i would be able to manage that. wanna chrome remote desktop in and see it on my local server? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error message you get when you pass jQuery a string which it can't parse as a selector. For example:

```js
$('%%').each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This throws

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %%

because `%%` is not a valid selector.

Somewhere in your code, you're probably passing a dynamic string to `$`, and it's throwing an error. Check the stack trace: the first line that is *not* from jQuery will show you the source of the problem, eg:

[image]

Click on that link and the browser will take you to the problematic line. From there, you can figure out what invalid string you're passing to `$` and can fix it up so that a valid selector is passed instead.